# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied | @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have created a separate customize component for `TextField` in the jetpack component and I import the libraries below, but it's throwing the error like below in the picture

```
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
```

but I couldn't able to compile it, it's throwing the error

my implementation

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.material.TextFieldDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalSoftwareKeyboardController
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction

import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview


@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun NoteInputText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    label: String,
    maxLine: Int = 1,
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onImeAction: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onTextChange,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        maxLine = maxLine,
        label = {
            Text(text = label)
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
            onImeAction()
            keyboardController?.hide()
        }),
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    NoteInputText(text = "hello", label = "nam", onTextChange = {})
}
```

that error I'm getting

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `maxLine: Int = 1,` to `maxLines: Int = 1,`  
Mistake was in naming, there is no `maxLine` in TextField

Comment: FFS I had similar issue with misspelled `keyBoardActions` so easily done, would if nice if the IDE didn't highlight blue like all the correctly named fields!